# How to pass multiple variables from AJAX to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have AJAX code here that pass multiple values to PHP. But the problem is that the PHP can't get the value pass by AJAX and nothing is added on the database. However in my submit button I have an onclick event that calls `addAnnouncement()` and I think it is working because I put an alert in my ajax code and everytime I click that button it says OK.
So I think the part of the problem is in the passing of the variables.

What do you think is the problem in my code?

**AJAX CODE:**

```
  function addAnnouncement()
{
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var announcement = document.getElementById("announcement").value;

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }




    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            if(xmlhttp.status==200){
                alert("OK");
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
      }

     var variables = "subject=SAMPLE&name=HARVEY&announcement=HELLO";
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "addAnnouncement.php", true);          
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");      
      xmlhttp.send(variables);  

     return false;
          }
```

This is the PHP code that gets the values pass by AJAX.
**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['announcement'];
$dateTimeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


$query = "INSERT INTO table_announcement(subject, name, text, dateTimePosted)". 
                "VALUES('$subject', '$name' , '$text', '$dateTimeNow')";
$data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());       

if($data){
    echo "ADDED!";
}   
else{
    echo "ERROR!";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Beware of SQL injection in your code.

Comment: And what is the response of the XHR? Does it show `ERROR!`, implying that the query returned `FALSE`?

Comment: Okay thank you for that. I'll modify my code later. But do you think that's the reason why this is not working? sorry I'm newbie here.

Comment: And please look at your network tab in the Inspector to see if a network request is made and if so, what's sent.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel No it doesn't show anything, it only reloads the current page.

Comment: Do you use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` in the event handler? Please show your event handler.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Sorry I don't have my event handler. I posted here the complete code. I just have the `function addAnnouncement()` that is called when I click the submit button.

Comment: just a small recommendation, use jquery for your javascript. I mean javascript is good but jquery is easy and deals easily with problem like your's

Comment: @manish jQuery is not magic, it doesn't solve bugs caused by not stopping the default behaviour of an event handler.

Comment: Why did you edit your question? Was all that code actually there already?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel No I've just modified some of the code as per your suggestion in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just return `false` when exiting from the event handler to prevent the default behaviour of the submit button (i.e. submit the form):

```
function addAnnouncement() {
    // …
    return false;
}
```

Also check the status of your XMLHttpRequest when it reaches `readyState` 4 (it might be something different then 200) and properly encode query string parameters with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Last, but not least, your code is open to SQL injection. Fix that by using prepared statements (available in [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)).

Comment: Sir I've edited my question. I've also tried your suggestions, added a condition after the `readyState` which is `if(xmlhttp.status==200)`. And the alert OK now is not popping not like before. So it means that it does not pass the condition. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: @Harvey It is at least a problem that it doesn't give back status 200. Then you should debug further, outputting the status using `console.log` (or check what's sent using the network tab of the browser's inspector).

Comment: Okay, thank you. But how can I use `console.log` to output the status? Is there a tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: @Harvey Just output the status with `console.log(xmlhttp.status)` and look at the console (or better, look at the network tab).

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie here, last question where in part of the code will I put the `console.log(xmlhttp.status);`?

Comment: In the console it's just displaying `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle' `

Comment: @Harvey Before you check the status, you might want to output it. Where did you try to obtain `cycle`?

Comment: I type the `console.log(xmlhttp.status)` to the console and it says,  `ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined`.

Comment: No, don't type that in the console, insert that in your code before you check the status.